# Problems playing video with Windows Media Player in Winforms App

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, winforms, media-player

**Goal.** I created a 9-Form application in Visual Studio 2019, and I am trying to play a video file, in one of my forms, stored in the same folder with the executable file (.exe) of my winforms application.

**Steps.** I installed via the 'COM Components' the Windows Media Player feature, and showed in my Toolbox as it should be (Although the icon doesn't appear next to its title inside the Toolbox). After that, I drag 'n' dropped it in my form in order to write the following code based on Microsoft Documentation.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
      axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "video delphi.mp4";
}
```

**Actual Result.** Although when I am dragging the player in my form, it shows up as it should, but when I am running the application, it becomes blank as it was never being placed there or being dragged / used in my forms. I've checked from the properties that the player is visible and enabled. At some point, by pressing the play button I was able to hear only audio and no video.

**Errors / Notifications Received.** 1. When I first tried to see what was going on, I received a notification during the runtime of my app that the file isn't being supported, although insted of showing me the (.mp4) extension, it only showed (,) symbol. That notification was not coming from VS 2019 but from the player itself.
2. Currently I am receiving an C00D1179 error while the aforementioned notification doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: I don't believe that Windows Media player supports .mp4 without installing a codec. Here's a link that may be useful: https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm You can find others that may work as well.

Comment: Nope!!! I tried it!!!

Comment: I've added step-by-step instructions below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to play a .mp4 file using Windows Media Player, try the following which has been tested.

**Pre-requisites**: If not already installed, a "mp4" codec must be installed - such as [K-Lite codec pack](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) or another codec pack.

**VS 2019**:

Create a new project

- Click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- Select the following:
  [image]
- Click **Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**

  [image]
- Click **Next**
- Enter desired project name (ex: MediaPlayerTest)
- Click **Create**

**Add Reference**

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference...**
- Click **COM**
- Select **Windows Media Player**
- Click **OK**

**Open Solution Explorer**:

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Open Form1 in Designer**

- In Solution Explorer, double-click **Form1.cs**

**Open Toolbox**:

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Search: Windows Media Player
- If Windows Media Player isn't found, add it to the Toolbox.

**Add Windows Media Player to Toolbox** (if it doesn't already exist in the Toolbox)

- Right-click **All Windows Forms**
- Select **Choose Items...**.
- After it's finished loading, click **COM Components**.
- Check "Windows Media Player**.
  [image]
- Click **OK**
- Windows Media Player should now exist under "All Windows Forms" in the Toolbox.

**Add Windows Media Player to Form1**

- Drag Windows Media Player from the Toolbox onto Form1.

**Add Buttons to Form1**

- Drag two buttons from the Toolbox onto Form1
- Rename button1 to `btnPlay`
- Rename button2 to `btnStop`
- Double-click `btnPlay` to create the click event handler
- Double-click `btnStop` to create the click event handler

**Modify/add code to Form1.cs**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Form1.cs**
- Select **View Code**

Copy desired .mp4 file (ex: ocean.mp4) to the folder that your .exe file exists in.

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MediaPlayerTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "none";
        }

        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName), "ocean.mp4");
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = filename;
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //stop
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Media Player**:

- Run your program
- Click **Play** button

**Resources**:

- [Embedding the Windows Media Player Control in a C# Solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/embedding-the-windows-media-player-control-in-a-c--solution)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. The following day I posted my question, I was able to find out that the template I used was the simplw "Windows Forms App", and not one with "(.NET Framework)" in it. I tested it, I was extremelly frustrated with my stupidity, since I've finished my project already I can't start it from stratch, just for this mistake. Thank you again!!!