# Video color change AxWindowsMediaPlayer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

In my program (Windows Forms .NET, Visual Studio 2022) I am replaying a particular video (.mp4) whenever its corresponding button press occurs. In my form design, a PictureBox element with the first frame of the video overlays the Windows Media Player element with the video. When a key press occurs, I make the picture box element invisible after a 250 ms delay (to avoid showing the black background of the media player element). My issue is the color of the first frame looks darker compared to the video when it plays in the Windows Media Player element so video playback does not look smooth.

I don't understand why the colors look different because I extracted the first frame from the same program I used to edit the video (i.e. Adobe Photoshop). I also tried taking a screenshot of the video as it plays on the form and use that image but I still see a color change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69445915/problems-playing-video-with-windows-media-player-in-winforms-app), problem was solved by installing [K-Lite codec pack](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm)